# Unable to preview the image before upload inside html table

Tags: jquery, css, file

I am new to php and jquery, i am trying to preview the image before upload,

Here i also add more functionality, how to preivew the all the images before upload

Here is my code, I tried and followed this url, not working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

```js
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
      $(function(){
   $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
        $("#add_field").click(function () {
          $("#table_container").append($("#temp_div").html());
        });
      })
```

```css
.image-upload > input
{
    display: none;
}

.image-upload img
{
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <table id="table_container">
                <tr>
                    <th><label class="lbl-header">My Hobies</label></th>
                    <th><label class="lbl-header">Image</label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" name="hobies[]" value=""></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="image-upload">
                          <label for="file-input">
                              <img src="upload.jpg"/>
                          </label>
                          <input id="file-input" id="imgInp"  type="file" name="image[]" />
                          <img src="#" alt="image" id="blah">
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
               </table>
                 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thank for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for the first one?

If yes, what's your problem is that the new images upload field is basically non existent when the js is loading, so the new fields do not take the change into account.

Secondly you are using an id to do this, it's so wrong, you can only have one id, so you should use you change on a class.